# HTML tags not supported when sending emails in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, emails

This is my code to sending email

```
   function hook_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
     $options = array(
    'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
  );

  switch ($key) {
    case 'create_article':
      $message['from'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail');
      // $message['headers']['Cc'] = $params['cc'];

      $message['subject'] = 'SUBJECT';
      $message['body'][] = Markup::create($params['message']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Mails are getting without any issue.But some of the HTML tags are not supporting
Eg: **HTML bold,italics....**
I have also configured SMTP authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send HTML email with Drupal 8/9/10 "out of the box."

### Drupal 9/10

To send HTML email with Drupal 9/10, you should use the [Symfony Mailer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/symfony_mailer).  This module replaces the mail system in Drupal core to use Symfony's system, which includes support for HTML among many other things.

### Drupal 8

To send HTML email with Drupal 8, you can use the [Swift Mailer module](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer) (now unsupported, just like Drupal 8-- time to upgrade people), which has the following features:

> - Sending e-mails directly through a SMTP server of your choice, a
>   locally installed MTA agent such as sendmail or the mail functionality
>   provided by PHP.
> - Sending HTML (MIME) e-mails.
> - Adding file attachments to e-mails.
> - Adding inline images to e-mails.

The Commerce 2 documentation includes a [tutorial on how to install and configure the Swift Mailer module.](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/core/html-emails)

Comment: But HTML <br> tag is working.

Answer (score 0):

In D7 you need to install [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) and in your code add:

```
$message['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed';
```

Hopefully it's still the same on D8, give it a try.

Comment: I also used Mime Mail for Drupal 7, but I think Swift Mailer has more development momentum in Drupal 8.  For example, Swift Mailer is the recommendation for use with Commerce 2: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/core/html-emails

Comment: @PatrickKenny thanks for the info, I think he'll probably still need to add the code I posted above when sending programmatically with Swift Mailer.